# Javascript proxies were not generated for controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I enabled "Developer mode" on my account and visited my visualforce page and got an error that says "Javascript proxies were not generated for controller: may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe."

I read [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092ZfIAI) and it said to change my remote methods to global - and I did that, but the error persists.

Anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: The class should also be global. Did you try that?

Comment: as @sfdcfox said class should be global + all method should be defined as global as well regardless that is remote action or not.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the relevant code? Just the class declarations and method signatures should be sufficient.

Comment: You guys are correct - does someone want to add a solution so I can give it the correct answer?

Comment: @user1813867 any update on how this was resolved ?